# Flickering text on hover effect using pure CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

As the title suggests, when I hover over the main text, the corresponding text shows at the bottom first and then shows to the right. This flickering effect needs to go. How do I go about this?

DEMO: [**https://jsfiddle.net/h0nzojxg/**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0nzojxg/)

HTML

```
<div class="grow">
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 1</h2> 
      <p>Contrary One</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 2</h2> 
      <p>Contrary Two</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 2</h2> 
      <p>Contrary Two</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2, p, a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.grow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2a75a9;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  text-align: left;
}
.grow>div {
  min-height: 50px;
}
.grow p {
  opacity: 0;
}
.grow:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.grow:hover {
  width: 245px;
}
```

Comment: On the paragraph, try transitioning the opacity:  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

Comment: Thank you. However, the animation effect doesn't work anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/gbw5kd7u/

Comment: Is the <h2> and <p> displaying inline correctly?

Comment: Yes, except the animation is not working.

Comment: @G-Cyr Could you post that answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `white-space` to keep everything on a single line: https://jsfiddle.net/k0cwuzx4/

```css
h2,
p,
a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.grow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2a75a9;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  text-align: left;
}

.grow>div {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.grow p {
  opacity: 0;
}

.grow:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.grow:hover {
  width: 245px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grow">
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Contrary One</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Contrary Two</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Contrary Two</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
>
> The white-space CSS property sets how white space inside an element is handled.